# Python OOP How to get private attribute from another class

Tags: python, oop

I was taking a Python OOP test but I couldn't solve this problem.
So the classes intializers were already written. You can't really change that.
In the Employee class `def set_salary` had to have two parameters: bonus, and base_pay
also in the Employee class `def get_salary` has to return the sum of the bonus and base_pay.
I had no idea how to get the private instances.

```
class Salary:

    def __init__(self, base_pay=0, bonus=0):
        self.__base_pay = base_pay
        self.__bonus = bonus

    def set_bonus(self, y):
        self.__bonus = y

    def get_bonus(self):
        return self.__bonus

    def set_base_pay(self, y):
        self.__base_pay = y

    def get_base_pay(self):
        return self.__base_pay

    # Write methods Salary class here

class Employee:
    
    def __init__(self, name='', base_pay=0, bonus=0):
        self.__name = name 
        self.__salary = Salary(base_pay, bonus)


    def set_name(self, x):
        self.__name = x

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def set_salary(self, bonus, base_pay):
        self.__salary  = self.__salary(bonus) + self.__salary(base_pay)

    def get_salary(self):
        return self.__salary

    # Write methods for Employee class here
```

I tried to solve it but had no clue. Hope you can help so I understand and can use it later.
Thanks!

Comment: What should the `set_salary()` method do? Is that explained in the test?

Comment: Out of all methods, which ones are in the original problem and which ones are yours? `get_` and `set_` methods are quite un-Pythonic (were I the one who wrote those I would use `@property instead`).

Comment: @InSync getters and setters should be written after the initializers that were given.

Answer (score 1):

Your `set_salary` method should surely look like this

```py
def set_salary(self, bonus, base_pay):
    self.__salary.set_bonus(bonus)
    self.__salary.set_base_pay(base_pay)
```

and obviously `get_salary` which "has to return the sum of the bonus and base_pay" can just return their sum...

```py
def get_salary(self):
    return self.__salary.get_base_pay() + self.__salary.get_bonus()
```

Using the getter/setter methods that the `Salary` class (which you store an instance of in `self.__salary`) provides.

By the way, getters and setters are very weird to see in Python. Even though they might be typical in paradigmatic OOP languages like Java/C#, in Python we'd definitely rather use `@property` or just fields directly.

Comment: "*you can absolutely just access "private members" directly if you want*": No, I don't think so. Name mangling is at play here.

Comment: @InSync you're right

Answer (score 0):

Create the Proper method to access the private variable and call them inside child class and do the sum of that